# Query documents by most recent date

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple collection like this:

[image]

Each document has these fields:

- `actividades`: *list*
- `acuerdo`: *string*
- `corte`: *date*

I would like to query the documents by the most recent date that is saved in `corte`.

The first thing that comes to my mind would do something like this:

1. Query and order the collection by `corte` and then limit the results
   to 1
2. From that result get `corte` field. That is the most recent date
3. Query again filtering the documents that have this date in `corte`

Is this approach correct or is there a better way?

I'm using the web version of firestore (javascript)

Comment: you probably should state the environment (language) you are working with ...

Comment: Edited. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best you can do, without a more complete understanding of how you are populating your data, and also perhaps some changes with the way you populate the database.  But, with client side persistence enabled, this is not an overly expensive strategy, since your second query will not incur a read for the (cached) document obtained from the first query.

Comment: Client side persistence is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the right approach to me. As Doug said: the client-side persistence works quite nicely in this case to minimize the charged read operations.

The common alternative would be to create a separate collection with documents that are only the dates. But in this case you'd still need two read operations: one from the collection of dates, the other from the avances collection. So you wouldn't save any read operations, but merely some (minimal) bandwidth.